# Flutter Hero like animation with AnimatedContainer in a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I wanted to animate a single container of a listview in a hero-like fashion but with more control over changes of color, font sizes, etc. Therefore I used AnimatedContainer but I have now the problem that the blue container isn't filling up so whole screen, only the right side of the screen and the rest is getting pushed out. How can I achieve that the blue Container is using the whole screen, therefore pushing the red Container out of his way?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class AnimationTestView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationTestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimationTestView> createState() => _AnimationTestViewState();
}

class _AnimationTestViewState extends State<AnimationTestView> {
  bool isBig = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double newHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Container(
            height: newHeight / 2,
            width: width / 2,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isBig = !isBig;
              });
            },
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              height: isBig ? newHeight : newHeight / 2,
              width: isBig ? width : width / 2,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4our.png)

[After Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S90tG.png)

Comment: Do you want it to fill the whole screen when you click on a Container?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Is it mandatory for your widgets to be in the ListView or did you do it unconsciously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class AnimationTestView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationTestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimationTestView> createState() => _AnimationTestViewState();
}

class _AnimationTestViewState extends State<AnimationTestView> {
  bool isBigRed = false;
  bool isBigBlue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double newHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isBigRed = !isBigRed;
              });
            },
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              height: isBigRed
                  ? newHeight
                  : isBigBlue
                      ? 0
                      : newHeight / 2,
              width: isBigRed
                  ? width
                  : isBigBlue
                      ? 0
                      : width / 2,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isBigBlue = !isBigBlue;
              });
            },
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              height: isBigBlue
                  ? newHeight
                  : isBigRed
                      ? 0
                      : newHeight / 2,
              width: isBigBlue
                  ? width
                  : isBigRed
                      ? 0
                      : width / 2,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation package from pub.dev and wrap your animated container within openContainer. To know how to use this package you will get many videos on YouTube.

Comment: I thought about that as well but I don't want a fade transition between text on the container. I want an animated transition between single elements.  But thank you for your answer :)